# JavaScript/Bootstrap - How to keep the sub-menu closed on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble keeping the sub-menu closed on the mobile version. 
It will always show as expanded and I've tried several solutions but it won't work.

On Desktop, it works totally fine, but I am not sure why it is expanded as default on the mobile version.

Could anyone help me keep the submenu "ADDITIONAL FEATURES" closed?

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse mega-menu navbar-responsive-collapse">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <!-- Why ClearDent -->
      <li class="menu-home dropdown"><a href="../" id="top-nav-2-home" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-fw"></i> Features</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#" id="navtab-2-cleardent" role="tab">
        <svg class="cleardent-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1147.6 1163">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M1147.6,581.5c0,321.2-256.9,581.5-573.8,581.5S0,902.6,0,581.5,256.9,0,573.8,0,1147.6,260.3,1147.6,581.5Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M808.3,237.7c-78.3-79.4-146.5-15.5-240.2-15.5-36.4,0-53-10.2-90.1-17-58-10.6-110.6,9.5-142.1,42.8-13.8,14.6-23.8,33.8-28.7,58.8a202.61,202.61,0,0,0-3.5,39c0,50.2,13.5,113.9,46.4,191.2,20.8,48.9,32.7,118.6,37.4,159.3,20.1,171.9,70.9,261.9,95,237.6,57.4-58.1-22.7-306.5,65.4-327.6,147.6-35.5,43.1,347.3,96.2,358.2C721.2,980.3,756.4,637.3,786,572.4,811.3,516.9,888.8,319.2,808.3,237.7Z"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="feature-icon-text">ClearDent</span></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="../features/clearconnect-plus-messaging.html" id="navtab-2-clearconnect" role="tab">
        <svg class="clearconnect-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 22.16 22.16">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M22.16,11.08A11.08,11.08,0,1,1,11.08,0,11.08,11.08,0,0,1,22.16,11.08"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M11.08,13,9.42,11.54,4.69,15.6a1,1,0,0,0,.66.26H16.81a1,1,0,0,0,.66-.26l-4.73-4.06Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M17.47,6.56a.94.94,0,0,0-.66-.26H5.35a1,1,0,0,0-.66.26L11.08,12Z"/>
          <polygon class="cls-2" points="4.39 7.14 4.39 15.08 9.01 11.15 4.39 7.14"/>
          <polygon class="cls-2" points="13.15 11.15 17.77 15.08 17.77 7.13 13.15 11.15"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="feature-icon-text">ClearConnect</span></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="../features/clearmobile.html" id="navtab-2-clearmobile" role="tab">
        <svg class="clearmobile-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1920">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M1920,960c0,530.21-429.79,960-960,960S0,1490.21,0,960,429.79,0,960,0s960,429.79,960,960"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M1168.55,429.73h-417A76.48,76.48,0,0,0,675,506.25v907.49a76.48,76.48,0,0,0,76.51,76.51h417a76.46,76.46,0,0,0,76.43-76.51V506.25a76.46,76.46,0,0,0-76.43-76.51M908.86,475h102.33a6.67,6.67,0,0,1,0,13.34H908.86a6.67,6.67,0,1,1,0-13.34m-102-16a10.66,10.66,0,1,1-10.74,10.66,10.65,10.65,0,0,1,10.74-10.66m-48.44-6.41a17.07,17.07,0,1,1-17.07,17.07,17,17,0,0,1,17.07-17.07m228.24,998.82H933.29a30.59,30.59,0,1,1,0-61.18h53.38a30.59,30.59,0,1,1,0,61.18m225.9-85.44H707.4V554h505.17Z"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="feature-icon-text">ClearMobile</span></a></li>

      <li class="presentation" role="presentation"><a href="../features/PDE.html" id="navtab-2-perks" role="tab">
        <svg class="cleardent-perks-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
         <circle class="cls-1" cx="401.3" cy="401.8" r="398.3"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M488,464c-22.6,0-43.4,7.8-59.8,20.9l-102.5-64.1c3-13.7,3-28,0-41.7l102.5-64.1c16.4,13.1,37.2,20.9,59.8,20.9
          c53,0,96-43,96-96s-43-96-96-96s-96,43-96,96c0,7.2,0.8,14.1,2.3,20.8l-102.5,64.1C275.4,311.8,254.6,304,232,304c-53,0-96,43-96,96
          s43,96,96,96c22.6,0,43.4-7.8,59.8-20.9l102.5,64.1C392.8,546,392,553,392,560c0,53,43,96,96,96s96-43,96-96S541,464,488,464z"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="feature-icon-text">PDE</span></a></li>
        <li class="presentation dropdown-submenu" role="presentation"><a href="javacript:void(0);" id="navtab-2-perks" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <svg class="cleardent-perks-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1180 1180">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M1173.83,600c0,321.17-256.92,581.54-573.82,581.54S26.17,921.17,26.17,600,283.09,18.46,600,18.46,1173.83,278.82,1173.83,600Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M600,220.57c-209.22,0-379.43,170.21-379.43,379.43S390.78,979.43,600,979.43,979.43,809.22,979.43,600,809.22,220.57,600,220.57ZM416,657.49A57.49,57.49,0,1,1,473.52,600,57.56,57.56,0,0,1,416,657.49Zm184,0A57.49,57.49,0,1,1,657.49,600,57.56,57.56,0,0,1,600,657.49Zm184,0A57.49,57.49,0,1,1,841.46,600,57.56,57.56,0,0,1,784,657.49Zm0,0"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="feature-icon-text">Additional Features</span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="../features/clearvault.html" id="navtab-2-clearvault" >
        <svg class="clearvault-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1920">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M1920,960c0,530.21-429.79,960-960,960S0,1490.21,0,960,429.79,0,960,0s960,429.79,960,960"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M1312.38,856.11H1291.5V758.36c0-180.75-143.41-331.7-322.69-335-4.94-.09-14.73-.09-19.58,0-179.28,3.29-322.77,154.24-322.77,335v97.74H605.57c-32.15,0-58.4,33.19-58.4,74.26v490.09c0,41,26.26,74.52,58.4,74.52h706.81c32.23,0,58.49-33.53,58.49-74.52V930.37c0-41.07-26.26-74.26-58.49-74.26m-287.16,318.79V1323c0,17-14.21,31.37-31.19,31.37h-70.1c-16.9,0-31.11-14.38-31.11-31.37V1174.89c-16.46-16.2-26.08-38.65-26.08-63.34,0-47.05,36.31-87.34,82.49-89.25,4.85-.17,14.64-.17,19.58,0,46.18,1.91,82.49,42.2,82.49,89.25,0,24.7-9.62,47.14-26.08,63.34M1153.9,856.11H764.14V758.36c0-107.62,87.52-196.7,194.88-196.7s194.88,89.08,194.88,196.7Z"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="feature-icon-text">ClearVault</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="../features/clearinsight.html" id="navtab-2-clearinsight">
        <svg class="clearinsight-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1920.09">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M960,0C429.87,0,0,429.87,0,960s429.87,960.09,960,960.09S1920,1490.21,1920,960,1490.21,0,960,0M556.82,1536.05H403.27V1197.51c57.54,16,96,27.47,153.54,34.57Zm211.17,0H633.59V1239.36c0,.69,24.7,1.3,39.25,1.3,33.88,0,56.76-2.08,95.14-6.07Zm211.25,0H844.84v-313.5c38.39-10.66,95.92-26,134.39-45.49Zm211.25,0H1056V1141.88c57.54-28.94,96-63.6,134.48-103.46Zm230.32,0H1267.26V961.39c76.77-85.09,121.05-193.32,143.49-289.33h10.05Zm-40-902.46c-69.23,441.66-547.37,676-962.51,531.51-14.38-5-8.49-23.48,6.15-21.23,333.6,52.51,626.74-203,678.39-510.28H949.43l140.11-124.78,140.2-123.48,280.31,248.25Z"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="feature-icon-text">ClearInsight</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="../features/bonus.html" id="navtab-2-perks">
        <svg class="cleardent-perks-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1180 1180">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M1173.83,600c0,321.17-256.92,581.54-573.82,581.54S26.17,921.17,26.17,600,283.09,18.46,600,18.46,1173.83,278.82,1173.83,600Z"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M600,220.57c-209.22,0-379.43,170.21-379.43,379.43S390.78,979.43,600,979.43,979.43,809.22,979.43,600,809.22,220.57,600,220.57ZM416,657.49A57.49,57.49,0,1,1,473.52,600,57.56,57.56,0,0,1,416,657.49Zm184,0A57.49,57.49,0,1,1,657.49,600,57.56,57.56,0,0,1,600,657.49Zm184,0A57.49,57.49,0,1,1,841.46,600,57.56,57.56,0,0,1,784,657.49Zm0,0"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="feature-icon-text">Extra Perks</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="../features/clearsupport.html" id="navtab-2-clearsupport">
        <svg class="clearsupport-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1920">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M1920,960c0,530.21-429.79,960-960,960S0,1490.21,0,960,429.79,0,960,0s960,429.79,960,960"/>
          <path class="cls-2" d="M1426.6,778.15c-8.06-77.9-33.53-183.87-106.58-272-79.63-95.92-197.65-148.78-351-157.1-152.76-8.23-271,31.37-351.19,118.1-90.12,97.57-109.27,229.45-112,307.26C466.69,782.48,437,818.18,437,860.55v223.9c0,48.35,38.65,87.86,85.87,87.86,2.17,0,4.25-.17,6.33-.35,21.14,84.92,106.49,335.6,379,371.64C927.76,1560.77,961.12,1572,999,1572c60.4,0,109.35-28.59,109.35-63.95s-49-63.95-109.35-63.95c-51.21,0-94.19,20.71-106,48.52-237-43.41-304.84-269.31-319.91-337.16a88.31,88.31,0,0,0,29.11-37.69c54.68,172,194.18,294.35,357.78,294.35s303.1-122.35,357.78-294.35c12.91,31.89,43.67,54.5,79.37,54.5,47.22,0,85.87-39.51,85.87-87.86V860.55c0-37.69-23.57-70-56.41-82.4M960,500.87c-169.92,0-313.85,132-363.67,314.54a87.35,87.35,0,0,0-43.41-37.09C555.33,708.22,572,586.39,652,499.91c70.27-75.82,176.07-110.48,314.54-103,139.77,7.63,246.52,54.76,317.49,140,62.56,75.3,86.22,167.67,94.62,237.86a86.62,86.62,0,0,0-55,40.64C1273.84,632.83,1129.91,500.87,960,500.87"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="feature-icon-text">Assistance</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- End Why ClearDent --> 
      <!-- About -->
      <li class="menu-about"> <a href="../about/" id="top-nav-2-about"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> About </a></li>
      <!-- End About -->
      <!-- Blog -->
      <li class="menu-marketing-guide"><a href="../marketing/" id="top-nav-2-blog"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-fw"></i> Blog</a></li>
      <!-- End Blog --> 
      <!-- Support -->
      <li class="menu-support"><a href="../support/" id="top-nav-2-support"><i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-fw"></i> Support</a></li>
      <!-- End Support --> 
      <!-- More Menu -->
      <li class="menu-more dropdown"><a href="javacript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-fw"></i> More</a>
        <ul id="feature-dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="menu-local-reps"> <a href="../free-tools/regional-reps.html" id="top-nav-2-local-reps"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i> Regional Reps </a></li>
          <li class="menu-jobs"><a href="../free-tools/dental-jobs-listing.html" id="top-nav-2-jobs"><i class="fa fa-comments fa-fw"></i> Dental Jobs Listing</a></li>
          <li class="menu-videos"><a href="../free-tools/training-videos.php" id="top-nav-2-videos"><i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-fw"></i> Training Videos</a></li>
          <li class="menu-forms"><a href="../free-tools/forms-and-specs.html" id="top-nav-2-downloads"><i class="fa fa-download fa-fw"></i> Forms &amp; Specs</a></li>
          <li class="menu-events"><a href="https://cleardent.eventbrite.com" target="_blank" id="top-nav-2-events"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> Events</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- End More Menu --> 
      <!-- Demo Menu-->
      <li class="search-menu"><div class="search" onClick="window.location='../demo';"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i><strong class="search-text"> DEMO</strong></div></li>
      <!-- End Demo Menu --> 
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/end container--> 
</div>
```

Please don't mind the path codes for SVGs, it was the code from the previous developer who worked on this site.

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Must be something in your JavaScript, because nothing in the code you provided would cause it to expand on mobile automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely due to something in the script, or you have the logic backwards in the stylesheet. Could you share the CSS for the menu and the JS, if any?